# Assigning LINQ Results to child Property - InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have two tables, Project and ProjectSshasp.

I have two models, `ProjectModel` and `ProjectSshasp`. One of my properties in my ProjectModel is:

```
public virtual ProjectSshasp ProjectSshaspModel { get; set; }
```

I get this error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[xxxAPI.Models.ProjectSshasp]' to type 'xxxAPI.Models.ProjectSshasp'.

On this line:

```
if (projectSshaspModel != null)
 projectModel.ProjectSshaspModel = (ProjectSshasp)projectSshaspModel;
```

Here is the full code:

```
    public virtual ProjectSshasp ProjectSshaspModel { get; set; }


       [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectModel>> GetProjectModel(Guid id)
    {
        //var projectModel = await _context.Project.FindAsync(id);
        var projectModel = await _context.Project
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ProjectID == id);


        var projectSshaspModel = _context.ProjectSshasp
                .Where(a => a.ProjectID  == id);

        if (projectSshaspModel != null)
            projectModel.ProjectSshaspModel = (ProjectSshasp)projectSshaspModel;

        if (projectModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

            return Ok(new { projectModel });


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
var projectSshaspModel = _context.ProjectSshasp
            .Where(a => a.ProjectID  == id);
```

With:

```
var projectSshaspModel = _context.ProjectSshasp
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProjectID  == id);
```